# vncserver-x11-serviced.service not working in Raspbian strech

Tags: vnc, raspbian-stretch

I tried to activate the vnc service but it does not work for unknown reason. I tried two clients without success.
The service is running for sure and a desktop is started in the pi. I try to connect with following address pi0002:1 or pi0002:0.
Below is the status of the service and its output when connecting.

systemctl status vncserver-x11-serviced.service

```
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vncserver-x11-serviced.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-09-26 13:52:45 CEST; 9min ago
 Main PID: 458 (vncserver-x11-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/vncserver-x11-serviced.service
           ├─458 /usr/bin/vncserver-x11-serviced -fg
           ├─480 /usr/bin/vncserver-x11-core -service
           ├─504 /usr/bin/vncagent service 14
           ├─704 /usr/bin/vncserverui service 15
           └─730 /usr/bin/vncserverui -statusicon 7

Sep 26 13:52:46 pi0002 vncserver-x11[480]: AgentInitCheck: agent comms failure
Sep 26 13:52:46 pi0002 vncserver-x11[480]: ConsoleDisplay: Found running X server (pid=489)
Sep 26 13:53:00 pi0002 vncserver-x11[480]: Connections: connected: 192.168.188.83::40828
Sep 26 13:53:00 pi0002 vncserver-x11[480]: Connections: disconnected: 192.168.188.83::40828 ([EndOfStream] Disconnection by client)
Sep 26 13:55:38 pi0002 vncserver-x11[480]: Connections: connected: 192.168.188.83::40994
Sep 26 13:55:38 pi0002 vncserver-x11[480]: Connections: disconnected: 192.168.188.83::40994 ([EndOfStream] Disconnection by client)
Sep 26 13:56:22 pi0002 vncserver-x11[480]: Connections: connected: 10.1.2.10::46034
Sep 26 13:56:22 pi0002 vncserver-x11[480]: Connections: disconnected: 10.1.2.10::46034 ([EndOfStream] Disconnection by client)
Sep 26 13:57:32 pi0002 vncserver-x11[480]: Connections: connected: 192.168.188.83::41378
Sep 26 13:57:32 pi0002 vncserver-x11[480]: Connections: disconnected: 192.168.188.83::41378 ([EndOfStream] Disconnection by client)
```

Comment: I am getting a similar problem on stretch, including the agent comms failure message, but the additional message I see coming from vncserver-x11-serviced is [unable to open display ""] (without the brackets)

Comment: What are you using for a VNC client?  What are the IP addresses of the Pi and the machine running the client.  (Please edit this information into your question rather than responding in a comment.)

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but RealVNC have downgraded the IOS application but there is not a full explanation on the App Store and I could see nothing in their blog either.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/ you need

```
On the device you'll use to take control, download VNC Viewer. For best results, use the compatible app from RealVNC.
```

Once you download and install the compatible app from https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/ , enter the user name and password you normally use to log in to your user account on the Raspberry Pi. By default, these credentials are pi and raspberry.

Comment: This is a Pi-side issue, and not a problem with the device which he is using to take control.

Comment: As he stated, the service is enabled and running. The problem is connection from remote, where he stated that  using 2 different clients it gives a connection error. The client that works is the compatible one from the realvnc, as described in the manual. I had exactly the same problem.